# How do I redirect upon login a specific user based on role?

Tags: functions, redirect, login, user-roles

I'd like to force a user to a specific page upon login based on their role using

```
if ( current_user_can('contributor') )
```

and the main login function

```
function wp_loginout($redirect = '', $echo = true) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url(get_permalink()) ) . '">' . __('Log in') . '</a>';
    else
        $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_logout_url(get_permalink()) ) . '">' . __('Log out of account') . '</a>';

    if ( $echo )
        echo apply_filters('loginout', $link);
    else
        return apply_filters('loginout', $link);
}
```

I've tried a number of combinations and seem to be failing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

filter `login_redirect`:

```
function my_login_redirect_contributors() {
  if ( current_user_can('contributor') ){
      return 'url-to-redirect-to';
  }
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect_contributors');
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is a year old hopefully this can help some people.

I ran into a case where the accepted answer didn't work because the global `$current_user` was a `WP_User` object but had null values. The following code is what I found to work.  Note the use of the 3rd parameter `$user`:

```
function 22352_login_redirect( $redirect_url, $POST_redirect_url, $user ) {
  if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && $user->has_cap( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    $redirect_url = 'url-to-redirect-to';
  }
  return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', array( $this, 'wpse22352_login_redirect' ), 10, 3 );
```